# Standard events appear in event manager but can't find them in ads manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-events

In my Android App I am sending 3 standard facebook events:

1. FindLocation
2. CustomizeProduct
3. CompleteRegistration

All those events appear in Events Manager so I know they are being sent correctly:
[image]

But when I try to create Conversion Campaign in Ads Manager only Complete Registration is displayed:
[image]

Why can't I create campaign using FindLocation and CustomizeProduct events? What could be the issue? I have no clue what is wrong at the moment

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Did you find the solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set up a custom conversion based on one of these two events?

It will then appear on the Adset creation tab.